# Статический массив занимает место в исполняемом файле?

Tags: ассемблер, компиляция, exe, masm32, линковка

Есть программа на MASM32, в которой идёт работа со статическим массивом. При компоновке `.exe` файла, размер этого файла почему-то увеличивается вместе с увеличением размера массива.
Почему это происходит?
Компилирую и линкую через консоль:

```
ml /c /coff file.asm
link /subsystem:console file.obj
```

Comment: Код в студию...

Comment: Если массив инициализированный, то он целиком будет находиться в exe файле.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы создадите массив из 262144 элементов размером `dword`, инициализированный нулями (не обязательно нулями, ключевое слово - инициализированный):

```
dd 262144 dup 0
```

То в исполняемом файле он займет 262144 * 4 = 1048576 байта, т.е. 1 мегабайт (1024<sup>2</sup> байт). Т.е. в исполняемом файле этот массив и будет выглядеть как блок данных из 1048576 нулевых байт. И не важно, что в ассемблерном файле для создания этого массива достаточно написать одну строку.

Чтобы массив не занимал места в исполняемом файле, нужно, чтобы он был неинициализированным, и в секции, где он объявлен, находиться после кода и инициализированных данных:

```
dd 262144 dup (?)
```

После этой секции могут идти другие секции, но текущая секция получит свой фактически размер только после загрузки исполняемого файла в память. Если в секции есть только неинициализированные данные и нет кода (код - это фактически инициализированные данные), то секция в файле будет занимать 0 байт (не считая записи, описывающей секцию, в таблице секций).